# Bug in OpenERP version 7 selection field

Tags: odoo

I have problem in selection field of openerp 7.

I make a selection field like

```
'my_field': fields.selection([('0', 'Not Possible'), ('1', 'Possible)], 'Option']
```

But it does not show `Not Possible`  in the selection.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does the field show up at all? What do you see? Have you updated your module?

Comment: yes field show me, but not display the vaule whose key is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Zero '0' is usually considered as False. May be thats the problem. Please try by changing it to

```
'my_field': fields.selection([('n', 'Not Possible'), ('p', 'Possible)], 'Option']
```

Comment: Hello AnomA,Thanks for reply, But in my case i can not change my value. My selection field is function field which base base on another integer field value. If there value 0 in the field then also display value in selection. I try to give value more then 0 or minus value then display. Is there no way to do this??? Thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: If its a function field then on return of the function add a check condition, it return_value == 0, then return 'n' otherwise return 'p'

Answer (score 2):

I'm not even sure if it's valid syntax

Shouldn't:

```
'my_field': fields.selection([('0', 'Not Possible'), ('1', 'Possible)], 'Option']
```

Be:

```
'my_field': fields.selection([('0', 'Not Possible'), ('1', 'Possible)], 'Option')
```

Comment: Good catch! I'll bet nobody else tried the line and found the discrepancy between the right square bracket and the parentheses.